# Pygame seemingly crashes with no error message

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on creating an AI to play the classic game Snake, and have implemented it somewhat successfully, however every so often the program crashes upon reaching its target. I'm using a modified version of A* for pathfinding and pygame for the graphics.

```py
import numpy as np
import pygame
import random


# Set constants for program
GRID_WIDTH = 25
GRID_HEIGHT = 25

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


displayX = 500
displayY = 500

SCALEX = displayX/GRID_WIDTH
SCALEY = displayY/GRID_HEIGHT



# Setyp pygame
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayX,displayY))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake') 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



# Mainly stores values at each point in the game area
class Block():
    def __init__(self, x, y, val):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.val = val # Stores what type this block is e.g. snake or fruit

        self.f = 0 # Values for A-Star Algorithm
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0

    def get_value(self):
        return self.val

    def set_value(self, new_val):
        self.val = new_val

    def set_cost(self, g, h):
        self.g = g
        self.h = h
        self.f = self.h - self.g

    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent # Used for retracing the path

class Snake():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.L = 4 # Length of snake
        self.body = [] # List of all parts in snake
        self.body.append([x, y])

        self.path = None

    def move(self, board):
        print(self.path)
        if self.path == None or self.path == []: # Check if a path exists
            self.A_Star(board) # If not calculate path
        else:
            self.x = self.path[0][0] # Move to next point in path then remove it from list
            self.y = self.path[0][1]
            self.path.pop(0)
            self.body.append([self.x, self.y]) # Add body part
            self.body = self.body[-self.L:]

    def get_snake(self):
        return self.body[-self.L:]

    def get_head(self):
        return [self.x, self.y]

    def eat(self): # Increase length and reset path
        self.L += 1
        self.path = None


    def A_Star(self, board): # Modified version of A Star to prioritise moving away from target
        start = board.get_grid()[self.x, self.y]
        end = board.get_fruit()

        if start != None and end != None:
            open_list = []
            closed_list = []

            current = start
            open_list.append(current)
            while open_list != []:
                current = open_list[0]
                for block in open_list:
                    if block.f > current.f:
                        current = block
                open_list.remove(current)
                closed_list.append(current)

                if current == end:
                    path = self.retrace_path(start, end)
                    return True

                neighbours = board.get_node_neighbours(current)
                for neighbour in neighbours:
                    if neighbour.get_value() != "body" and not neighbour in closed_list:
                        if not neighbour in open_list:
                            neighbour.set_cost(neighbour.g, board.get_distance(current, end))
                            neighbour.set_parent(current)
                            if not neighbour in open_list:
                                open_list.append(neighbour)
            return False   

    def retrace_path(self, start, end):
        current = end
        path = []
        while current != start:
            path.append([current.x, current.y])
            current = current.parent
        self.path = path
        self.path.reverse()

    '''def survive(self, board):
        neighbours = board.get_node_neighbours(board.get_grid()[self.x, self.y])
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if neighbour.val == "empty":
                self.path = [neighbour.x, neighbour.y]
                break'''




class Board():
    def __init__(self, snake):
        self.grid = np.empty((GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT), dtype=object)
        for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH):
            for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
                self.grid[x,y] = Block(x, y, "empty") # 2D Array containing all blocks
        self.fruit = self.new_fruit(snake) # Generate new fruit
        self.score = 0

    def check_fruit(self, snake): # Check collision between snake and fruit
        snake_head = snake.get_head()
        if snake_head[0] == self.fruit[0] and snake_head[1] == self.fruit[1]:
            snake.eat()
            self.score += 1
            self.fruit = self.new_fruit(snake)

    def check_death(self, snake): # Check to see if snake is dead
        snake_head = snake.get_head()
        snake_body = snake.get_snake()
        if snake_head[0] >= GRID_WIDTH or snake_head[0] < 0 or snake_head[1] >= GRID_HEIGHT or snake_head[1] < 0:
            return True
        collisions = 0
        for part in snake_body:
            if snake_head == part:
                collisions += 1
        if collisions == 2:
            return True

    def draw(self, snake): # Draw everything to screen
        self.grid = np.empty((GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT), dtype=object)
        for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH):
            for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
                self.grid[x,y] = Block(x, y, "empty")
        for part in snake.get_snake():
            self.grid[part[0], part[1]].set_value("body")
        self.grid[snake.get_head()[0], snake.get_head()[1]].set_value("head")
        self.grid[self.fruit[0], self.fruit[1]].set_value("fruit")

        for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH):
            for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
                if self.grid[x, y].get_value() == "fruit":
                    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,RED,(x*SCALEX,y*SCALEY,SCALEX,SCALEY))
                elif self.grid[x, y].get_value() == "body" or self.grid[x, y].get_value() == "head":
                    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,WHITE,(x*SCALEX,y*SCALEY,SCALEX,SCALEY))


    def new_fruit(self, snake): # Generate a new fruit location
        complete = False
        fail = False
        while not complete:
            fruit_loc = [random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH-1), random.randint(0, GRID_HEIGHT-1)]
            for part in snake.get_snake(): # Check that fruit is not in snake
                if part == fruit_loc:
                    fail = True
            if not fail:
                complete = True
        return fruit_loc


    def get_node_neighbours(self, block): # Get surrounding blocks from block
        neighbours = []
        options = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]]
        for option in options:
            checkX = block.x + option[0]
            checkY = block.y + option[1]

            if checkX >= 0 and checkX < GRID_WIDTH and checkY >= 0 and checkY < GRID_HEIGHT:
                neighbours.append(self.grid[checkX,checkY])
        return neighbours

    def get_distance(self, start, end): # Get distance between two points
        dx = abs(start.x - end.x)
        dy = abs(start.y - end.y)

        return dx + dy - 1

    def get_grid(self):
        return self.grid

    def get_fruit(self):
        return self.grid[self.fruit[0], self.fruit[1]]


def main():
    snake = Snake(0, 0)
    board = Board(snake)
    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                break

        snake.move(board) # Move snake


        if board.check_death(snake): # End program if snake is dead
            running = False
            break

        board.check_fruit(snake) # Call fruit check

        gameDisplay.fill(BLACK) # Draw to screen
        board.draw(snake)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)

main()
pygame.quit()
```

No error messages appear and the only way to tell that the program has stopped is that pygame no longer allows you to quit out and crashes instead. As far as I can tell the point at which it happens if completely random but occurs on most rounds. The snake will reach the fruit but will stop right before eating it.

Comment: *"the only way to tell that the program has stopped is that pygame no longer allows you to quit out and crashes instead."* No, splatter your code with print statements to see what part is running and hence narrow down where the crash is. (Also, can use Python debuggers, but the memory behavior in debug can differ)

Comment: Is this actually a hang rather than a crash? (all the more reason to use print statements to narrow it down). If you press Ctrl-C to interrupt, post us the stacktrace telling you which line it was hanging on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the method `new_fruit` in the class `Board`. You've generated and endless loop. Actually if the random position fails at the first try, `fail` will stay `True` forever.

`fail = False` has to be set in the outer loop, rather than before the loop:

```py
class Board():
    # [...]

    def new_fruit(self, snake): # Generate a new fruit location
        complete = False
        #  fail = False
        while not complete:

            fail = False # <----

            fruit_loc = [random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH-1), random.randint(0, GRID_HEIGHT-1)]
            for part in snake.get_snake(): # Check that fruit is not in snake
                if part == fruit_loc:
                    fail = True
            if not fail:
                complete = True
        return fruit_loc
```

Comment: I tried that. This breaks the game and doesn't remove the bug.

Comment: @DanielF Sorry, but you are wrong. It works fine. I've tested it. Anyway that bug is obvious.

Comment: I stand corrected. You are right, that is the solution. It actually froze because there was no longer a way to reach the fruit. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your `(x*SCALEX,y*SCALEY,SCALEX,SCALEY)` to `(int(x*SCALEX),int(y*SCALEY),int(SCALEX),int(SCALEY))`